# Write a variable with special character to a file in batch

Tags: file, batch-file, output

I am reading a variable in my batch script.

```
set /p filemask=Enter Your Filemask:
```

User can enter special characters > < as part of input

Example: Enter Your Filemask: *.pdf<1D

Now I have to write this variable to a file

```
echo get %filemask% >> winscp.txt
```

The problem is its trying to read input from file 1D and showing error

I tried

```
echo get "%filemask%" >> winscp.txt
```

But it's writing " to the file which should not be there.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way:

```
set /p "filemask=Enter Your Filemask:"
set "filemask=%filemask:>=^>%"
set "filemask=%filemask:<=^<%"


echo get %filemask% >> winscp.txt
```

OR

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /p "filemask=Enter Your Filemask:"
echo get !filemask! >> winscp.txt
```